# Doubly-linked list implementation not working

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, doubly-linked-list

I'm new to object-orientated programming and to this site.

I've been working on this program for a university-project for quite a while (or at least I'm trying to). I have to create a program that deals with doubly-linked lists, to be more precise, I need to implement the following things:

- `class Node`
- `class LinkedList`
- Various methods.

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
        self.next_node = None
        self.previous_node = None

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.last = None

    def __str__(self):
        return 'This is the value: '.format(self.first)

    def append(self, value):
        new_node = Node()
        self.first = new_node

def main():
    myList = LinkedList()
    myList.append(20)
    print(myList)
```

I'd expect the output to be: `"This is the value: 20"`.

But the output I get is: `"This is the value: "`.

What is my mistake? Either my `append` method or my `__str__` method don't work correctly (or neither do). (It's probably something really obvious)

Comment: Your not using value in your append method.

Comment: Suggest you read [**_How to debug small programs_**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `{}` to the string to tell format where to put the value.

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'This is the value: {}'.format(self.first)
```

See the Python docs for [string format examples](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-examples).

And, per @Jeremy's comment, you also need to assign the value to the new Node and add a **str**() function to the Node class.

This should work:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value # <- store the value in the object
        self.next_node = None
        self.previous_node = None

    def __str__(self):             # <- return the value as a string
        return str(self.value)

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.last = None

    def __str__(self):
        return 'This is the value: {}'.format(self.first)

    def append(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value) # <- pass value to the Node
        self.first = new_node
main()
    myList = LinkedList()
    myList.append(20)
    print(myList)
```

Comment: Thanks that already helped a lot. I added the {} but now I get the following output: 'This is the value: <__main__.Node object at 0x00521C90> 

How can I get the actual content of that object?

Comment: See my updated answer for this and please accept if it solved your problem.